# Extra argument in call swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to append two values to my variable `countryAndCode`.
I get the error: `Extra argument 'code' in call` which does not make any sence to me because `countryAndCode` is taking two values: Country and Code??

What have I done wrong?

Here is my code:

```
func startObersvingDB() {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("UserInformation").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

            if let title = snapshot.value!["usersUID"] as? String {
                self.tableData.append(title)


                if let name = snapshot.value!["userName"] as! String? {

                    self.tableDataNames.append(name)



                    for i in 0...self.tableData.count {
                        var countryAndCode: [(country:String, code: String)]
                        countryAndCode.append(self.tableData[i], code: self.tableDataNames[i])
                    }



                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                } else {
                    print("Noget virker ikke i startObservingDB")
                }



            }
        })


    }
```

If it is relevant; I am trying to create a search bar that is showing the name of the user, while showing their picture also (which is why I need the id in tableData).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to encapsulate the arguments you are passing in, in brackets.

Change this:
`countryAndCode.append(self.tableData[i], code: self.tableDataNames[i])`

to:
`countryAndCode.append((self.tableData[i], code: self.tableDataNames[i]))`

The reason you need to this is because you are declaring your array with `[(country:String, code: String)]` with the brackets encapsulating the arguments inside the array, so you need to do the same when appending data to it.

Comment: Do you know why I am getting the error: `index out of range` at this code?: `countryAndCode.append((self.tableData[i], code: self.tableDataNames[i]))`

Comment: I think it's coming from the `tableData[i]` index not the countryAndCode array